# get PID from paramiko

Tags: python, paramiko

I can't find a simple answer for this: I'm using paramiko to log in and execute a number of processes remotely and I need the PIDs of each process in order to check on them at later times.  There doesn't seem to be a function in paramiko to get the PID of an executed command, so I tried using the following:

```
stdin,stdout,stderr = ssh.exec_command('./someScript.sh &;echo $!;)
```

I thought that then parsing through the stdout would return the PID, but it doesn't.  I'm assuming I should run the script in the background in order to have a PID (while it is running).  Is there a more simple, obvious, way of getting the PID?

Comment: @JohnZwinck, a solution that does not involve tweaking the remote command would involve patching the SSH daemon _on the server_, not the `paramiko` module running on the client. The answer by @SørenLøvborg seems to be the most proper way to me.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here's a way to obtain the remote process ID:

```
def execute(channel, command):
    command = 'echo $$; exec ' + command
    stdin, stdout, stderr = channel.exec_command(command)
    pid = int(stdout.readline())
    return pid, stdin, stdout, stderr
```

Comment: Just to be extra safe, you might use `&&` instead of `;` after the echo command.  That way there's no chance you'll read the wrong thing as the PID.

Comment: @JohnZwinck: Ehn, I guess. `echo $$` is required by POSIX and a built-in utility in essentially all shell implementations [since 1987 or so](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1355/why-is-echo-a-shell-built-in-command). If `echo $$` somehow fails, I'd say that all bets are off. :-)

Comment: @SørenLøvborg Isn't $$ the PID of the shell (not of the 'command' that is run)?

Comment: @DavidDoria Same thing. :-) The use of `exec` means that the executed command inherits the shell PID.

Answer (score -1):

I usually use the standard UNIX command `pidof <command name>`, when I check on the process later. AFAIK there is no simpler way.

OK, given your comment, you can solve it by wrapping your ./someScript.sh in a Python process that uses the subprocess module.

wrapper.py:

```
import subprocess
import sys
proc = subprocess.Popen(sys.argv[1])
print proc.pid
proc.wait() #probably
```

Then run

```
stdin,stdout,stderr = ssh.exec_command('./wrapper.py ./someScript.sh')
```

and read the output

Comment: Right, but this'll need a somewhat ugly hack for me - I'm logging into remote servers that probably have multiple users and certainly have multiple instances of my software running on them.  What I'm looking for is the PID of the specific job that I set running with exec_command.